# Mac automator to rerun a python script if first attempt failed

Tags: email, automator, python

I wrote a python script to automatically send emails and used automator to run it by run shell:

```
/usr/local/bin/python /Users/austin/PycharmProjects/assignments/assignments.py
```

This assignments.py prints 'successfully sent the mail' after emails are sent

I'm wondering if there is a way to let automator rerun this script if it did not receive the 'successfully sent the mail'

Comment: For example when the networking has problem.

Comment: Probably this could be done by using schedule in the python script. Still curious if automator can realize this.

Comment: The usual way is for a script to return a status code

Answer (score 1):

It really depends - is there any "pause" or do you want to continually keep sending emails? This sounds a bit SPAM-y?

If you have created a 'process' that does some checks and then if there is work to be performed - it does its work and when finished goes back to "sleep".  This sounds more like a daemon task loop.

You can leverage [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).  It will keep a daemon/process running indefinitely. I'd suggest you install your script in your **user** space not the system.  The only difference is it will not start up until you log into your Mac.